# Spring authorization server: logout via Postman

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I've managed to setup an OAuth2 identity provider using new Spring Authorization Server.
To execute some tests, I used Postman - OAuth2 Authentication flow and I was able to get
a JWT token without problems.
Token Refresh also works perfectly out of the box.
With the acquired token, I was able to secure an Api on another Spring Boot project,
after a quite long trial-and-error process.
Problem is, I've no idea about how to test logout process via Postman.
Is there anyone who could help me, providing a link to any example ?
Thank you in advance.

I'd expect the token to be invalidated after the process, so that it cannot be used anymore to secure API endpoints.

Comment: Considering your comments to my answer, you have a new problem (not linked to "logout with Postman") which could be originated in your Spring application configuration (both resource-server and authorization-server). Please create a new question about your client lib configuration for spring authorization server. It should include your client lib configuration as well as your Spring app dependencies (with versions), Java web security conf and security properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RP Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) is a standard way to invalidate user session on an authorization server with OIDC. Not all "OIDC" authorization servers comply with the spec when it comes to logout, but I think Spring's one does. Read the (short) spec to figure out how to find the logout endpoint URI from the `.well-known/openid-configuration` as well as how to build the logout request (method, params, etc.). **With this elements, you should be able to build your Postman request to invalidate user session on the OP.**

**JWTs are immutable, you can't invalidate it** (and even if you could, you'd never have the guaranty that you updated all the existing copies). It is valid from its issuance and until it expires. Period.

What you can invalidate are user sessions on:

- the client. This usually goes with token deletion
- the authorization server. When you do so, it should not be possible to:

  - get new access tokens with a refresh token issued before the logout (even if this refresh token is still valid)
  - introspect an access token issued before the logout (even if the access token is still valid)

If you can't trust the **client** to delete the access token when the user logs out and if the access tokens are not short lived enough to accept the risk of an access after logout, then you might have to switch the **resource server** from JWT decoding to token introspection. Yes, you can introspect a JWT, but no, introspection is not efficient at all.

As a side note, if you can't trust how client handles access tokens, you have a much bigger security issue than the remaining lifespan of access tokens after user logout...

### Developed answer to the 1st comment

**Login and logout are the responsibility of the client**, not of the resource server, and REST API are resource servers (it should depend on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and not of `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`.

My bet is the issue you are facing is not due to the access-token still being valid but that user sessions are still valid and that user login is done silently because of that => **call the `end_session_endpoint` on the authorization server as described in the spec linked above** (yes, you should follow the link and read the content).

You have several actions to take:

- make sure your REST API is configured as a resource server (and not as a client) and remove login and logout from there. I have written quite a few [tutorials on that subject](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).
- configure an OAuth2 client for users login and logout. It could be:

  - the Angular application itself using a lib like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). This lib is well documented and easy to use, just follow the link and browse to the doc.
  - a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend (a middleware on your server keeping sessions for the Angular app, handling login and logout, fetching tokens from the authorization server, storing this tokens in session and then replacing session cookies with access token before forwarding a request from the browser to the API). `spring-cloud-gateway` can be used as BFF if configured as OAuth2 client and using the `TokenRelay` filter. I have a complete BFF implementation with `spring-cloud-gateway` (and Angular) in [this specific tutorial from the collection linked above](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

Whatever implementation you choose for the OAuth2 client (public in the browser or confidential on your server), it is its responsibility to trigger the RP Initiated Logout to invalidate the user session on the authorization server

- the Angular lib I linked does it
- if you choose an OAuth2 client implementation with spring, you can configure an `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` (or `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler` in a reactive app) to redirect the user to the authorization server after the logout on your client so that both sessions are invalidated

Comment: The complete scenario will have an Angular app using Spring Authorization server to get authorization token. We've just implemented a proof of concept, and while we're able to get a token following oauth2 authentication flow and get our API endpoint secured, we're not able to logout: the token is still valid, we're not able to invalidate session. On backend site, log shows that we hit /oauth2/revoke endpoint, and then we're redirected to Spring login page. Angular library we're using complains that the revocation request failed,  but we can't understand why.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Indeed we're using angular-auth-oidc-client, but with a variation: the authorization server is also a resource server, a non-common scenario. I used to use Keycloak before -with a specific angular lib, and it worked without problems.
In our case, angular-auth-oidc-client calls /outh2/revoke token when logoff() method is invoked; Spring Authserver redirects to login page and angular-auth-oidc-client complains that the revoke request went wrong. Anyway I'll check samples you provided, I'm pretty sure I've missed something in sec config at Spring side.

Comment: There could be something missing in your Angular conf and as a consequence in the logout request: have you checked the value of the `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter in the request sent to your OP? It should point back to your Angular app.

Comment: We set a postLogoutRedirectUri in config, but it seems to be ignored. By the way, as far as I can understand from Spring's logs, the /oauth2/revoke request is made via POST.
I inspected the POST request payload, the post_logout_redirect_uri doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: You are switching to another question: you are not asking anymore how to logout using Postman (which is answered by the RP-Initiated Logout spec I linked). You should create another question about your client lib configuration, with the elements I list in my comment to your question.

Comment: Ok, I will create another question. I started with Postman just because I used Postman to check if Spring config was right or not, otherwise I could have had two distinct sides to check: backend and angular config. Thanks a lot for the time you spent helping me, I really appreciate it. I'll check the examples you provided, and I'll start another more specific question.

Comment: You should be able to invalidate the session on the authorization server using Postman: just build the request as specified in the spec. If it doesn't work, then your spring app is misconfigured (or my answer is wrong). Otherwize, your issue is on the client lib side (and maybe can this answer be accepted?)

Comment: By the way Scorpio, it is a good practice to upvote useful answers and to accept it when it solves the (initial) problem. It helps others browsing through a result search that something useful was answered to a question similar to the one they have.

Comment: I just accepted your answer, still cannot upvote it due to my low reputation on stackoverflow,sorry for that. Thanks for your answer, I believe you put me on the right track.