# Spring oauth2 authorization server success logout but JWT token still can be used to introspect or userinfo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server, spring-boot-security, spring-authorization

I am successfully authenticate and get `access_token`,`refresh_token`, and `id_token`.

1. Once access_token generated, I am creating a request to userinfo or introspect, it is saying that token `active: true`
2. Then use `refresh_token` to retrieve new access_token. Once I got new `access_token`, I am trying to make request to `/introspect`  with old token and saying `active:false`
3. When I use `id_token` to logout, I am redirected to `post_logout_redirect_uri`. But when make request to `/introspect` it return `active:true` also with all token details too.

In point number 2 it was clear that my previous `access_token` is not valid anymore. I think /logout will also update my token to become `active:false`, but thats not happen.

Here is my config file:

```
private final KeyManager keyManager;
private final DataSource dataSource;
private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain oauthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(httpSecurity);
    httpSecurity
        .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(
            customizer -> customizer.clientRegistrationEndpoint(
                clientRegistrationEndpoint -> clientRegistrationEndpoint.authenticationProviders(CustomClientMetadataConfig.configureCustomClientMetadataConverters())
            )
        )
        .registeredClientRepository(jdbcRegisteredClientRepository());

    httpSecurity
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Bean
JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
    ...
}

@Bean
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    ...
}

@Bean
JdbcRegisteredClientRepository jdbcRegisteredClientRepository() {
    ...
}

@Bean
RegisteredClient registeredClientRepository() {
    ...
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> 
            authorize
                .requestMatchers("/api-docs","/api-docs/*", "/swagger-ui/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(customizer -> Customizer.withDefaults())
        .logout(customizer -> Customizer.withDefaults())
        .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);

    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    ...
}

@Bean
OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtTokenCustomizer() { 
    ...
}
```

I am using

- spring-boot-starter-security:3.2.2
- spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.2.1
- spring-security-cas:6.2.1

Comment: i don't think token revocation happens automatically, you would have to implement it yourself, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356073/java-spring-cannot-logout-properly

Comment: @JAsgarov is correct, logging out has no direct effect on issued tokens. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/75689698/15835039.